# string concatenation of character and string

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string s1 = "Alice";
    s1 +='\0';
    s1 +='\0';
    cout << s1.size() << endl;         // output: 7

    string s2 = "Alice";
    s2 += "\0";
    s2 += "\0";
    cout << s2.size() << endl;         // output: 5
}
```

What is wrong here?

Please explain the difference between role of single quotes and double quotes in concatenation.

Comment: Do you know what a null-terminated string is?

Comment: There is no overload of `+=` taking an array of characters, so this first decays to a pointer. This then (indirectly) goes to `strlen()`. This is from the C legacy, basically.

Comment: I get a size output of 4 for `s2`.

Comment: Actually, the second output shoukd be 4...

Comment: @Harshit Gangwar It looks like a bug in the implementation of the class std::string because in the second case the output shall be equal to 4.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Bug - in which implementation of `std::string`? I can't repro on libstdc++, libc++, and MSVC's library.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The length of the string in the second case shall be equal to 4 not 5.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) / [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I assume OP just made a typo and that's all. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Vlad I've edited out the typo from OP.

Comment: @scohe001 Just in case, I'd wait for OP to confirm that it's indeed a typo, or they're using some exotic/old standard library.

Answer (score 8):

```
s1 +='\0';
```

adds the character to `s1` regardless of what the character is.

```
s2 += "\0";
```

adds a null terminated string to `s2`. Because of that, the embedded null character of the RHS is seen as a string terminator for the purposes of that function. In essence, that is equivalent to

```
s2 += "";
```

That explains the difference in output that you observed.

You can use [`std::string::append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) to append embedded null characters of a `char const*` object.

```
s2.append("\0", 1);
```

Comment: @R Sahu This explains nothing. There is a bug of the class implementation in the library.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow nope, there isn't. It's impossible to know if a null-terminated string has any embedded zeros. After all, the `\0` character is the only way to know if the string ended!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, please elaborate.

Comment: @RSahu In both assignment statements there is appended the same string literal "\0". So in fact nothing is appended.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, appending the null character to a `std::string` is not a noop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow with "both", you don't mean `s2 += "\0";` and `s1 +='\0';`, do you? `'\0'` is **not** a string literal.

Comment: @RSahu One more in the second example there is appended the same string literal "\0". So the length of the original string will not be changed and its length will be equal to 4 not 5.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, https://ideone.com/GGJJcq. Do you not agree with the output?

Comment: @RSahu Reread my previous comment. I will not repeat the same one more.

Comment: @RSahu The question used to say that doing `s2 += "\0";` twice increased the string length by one. That was edited out (not by OP), assumed to be a typo. Vlad probably assumes it's not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Does anyone have a resource like official documentation on how this happens? I see what the code is outputting but it just seems wrong.